# Bind ASP.NET 2.0 GridView to my own IList<T>.SomeMemberOfMyOwnCustomType.SomeProperty

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Let's say I have data like such:

```
class Location
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

class Friend
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string FriendName { get; set; }
    public Location Address { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool IsReliable { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I bind an ASP.NET 2.0 GridView control to my own IList like so:

```
GridView1.DataSource = new List<Friend>
{
    new Friend { Name = "...", Age = 22, ... }
};

GridView1.DataBind();
```

But I want to have only the following columns in my GridView with the following custom captions/column headers:

1. FriendName (Column Caption: Friend Name)
2. City  (Column Caption: City)
3. Age (Column Caption: Age)

How do I do that?

In other words, how do I bind a GridView control to a custom members of my own custom IList selectively?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been a few years I don't touch webforms grids but IIRC you can either do that on the grid side, using the `<Columns>` notation:

```
<asp:GridView ...>
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="FriendName"
        readonly="true"      
        headertext="Friend Name"/>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Address.City"
        readonly="true"      
        headertext="City"/>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Age"
        readonly="true"      
        headertext="Age"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

or use the IEnumerable/Linq extensions to transform your resuls as so:

```
GridView.DataSource = friends.Select(friend => 
     new { FriendName, City = friend.Address.City, Age });
```

and create a similar `<Columns>` notation for this new output, you will also need this for the customized headertext.

EDIT: In case the DateField="Address.City" won't work, there is the templateField option, with the `<ItemTemplate>` you can simply `<%# Eval("Address.City") %>` in its content.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="FriendGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"> 
    <Columns> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Friend Name" 
            DataField="FriendName" SortExpression="FriendName" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Age" 
            DataField="Age" SortExpression="Age" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City"  
            DataField="Address.City" SortExpression="Address.City" /> 
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Check this: [ASP.NET: GridView and Business Objects](http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2010/01/24/asp-net-gridview-and-business-objects.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the columns for your grid and map them in your code in your page_load, call the generateColumns subroutine and then once that has finished, call a binding on it. The GenerateColumns could look like this:

```
Private Sub GenerateContactGridColumns()
    Dim clmName As New BoundField()
    clmName.DataField = "FriendName"
    clmName.HeaderText = "Name"

    Dim clmCity As New BoundField()
    clmCity.DataField = "City"
    clmCity.HeaderText = "City"

    Dim clmEdit As New CommandField()
    clmEdit.ButtonType = ButtonType.Image
    clmEdit.EditImageUrl = Me.ThemeImagesPath & "/edit.gif"
    clmEdit.DeleteImageUrl = Me.ThemeImagesPath & "/delete.gif"
    clmEdit.ShowEditButton = True
    clmEdit.ShowDeleteButton = True

    gvContacts.Columns.Clear()
    gvContacts.Columns.Add(clmName)
    gvContacts.Columns.Add(clmCity)
    gvContacts.Columns.Add(clmEdit)
End Sub
```

Also, I usually use Entity framework and so the entity can be added to using a partial class and then I can define a property in the entity that delves into sub objects. For instance, friend can have a city property that returns address.city.